# Error while recreating host in unity netcode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

Hi Im working on an online game and everything works fine exept when I try to restart the host for new game. I get this error :

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Unity.Netcode.Components.NetworkAnimator.OnClientConnectedCallback (System.UInt64 playerId) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.0/Components/NetworkAnimator.cs:447)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager.InvokeOnClientConnectedCallback (System.UInt64 clientId) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.0/Runtime/Core/NetworkManager.cs:379)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager.HandleConnectionApproval (System.UInt64 ownerClientId, Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager+ConnectionApprovalResponse response) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.0/Runtime/Core/NetworkManager.cs:2077)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager.StartHost () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.0/Runtime/Core/NetworkManager.cs:1135)
Unity.Netcode.Editor.NetworkManagerEditor.OnInspectorGUI () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.0/Editor/NetworkManagerEditor.cs:321)
UnityEditor.UIElements.InspectorElement+<>c__DisplayClass59_0.<CreateIMGUIInspectorFromEditor>b__0 () (at <d2a4066bda954b169ad464ee5a8f02ff>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

it happens when `NetworkManager.Shutdown();` and then `NetworkManager.StartHost();`

I have tried testing the problem with an empty scene and everything was correct in that.
It should be a problem with any part of my code interacting with `NetworkManager.cs`.

I have tried doing some changes in `OnNetworkSpawn() { }` functions but didnt worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a problem with network animator as it says in error log :

Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.0/Components/NetworkAnimator.cs

it may be a issue with the booleans being sent with wrong names or null refrences